# How do I use Euler's result to find the sum of a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I am given:
$$ \zeta(4) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n^4}={\pi^4 \over 90} $$
I need to use it to find the sum of the following series using the above information.
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty {1\over{(k+2)^4}} $$
So, this is what I have so far:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty {1\over{(k+2)^4}} = \sum_{k=3}^\infty {1\over{k^4}}$$
but that is all I have... How do I get rid of the $k=3$?

Comment: What is the difference between this sum and $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^4}\,?$$

Comment: Are you referring to what I have so far? Or the original question?

Comment: To the last expression before the words "but that is all I have".

Comment: Well, one starts at 1 and the other starts at 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare $$\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^4}=\frac{1}{3^4}+\frac{1}{4^4}+\frac{1}{5^4}+\frac{1}{6^4}+\cdots$$
with$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^4}=\frac{1}{1^4}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{3^4}+\frac{1}{4^4}+\cdots}.$$
Hence we have $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^4}=\frac{1}{1^4}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^4}\iff \sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^4}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^4}\right)-\frac{1}{1^4}-\frac{1}{2^4}.$$

Comment: @Oyukyfairy: I hope my answer helps.

Comment: So @mathlove , I basically have to expand it out right? And then I solve for  $\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^4}$?

Comment: @Oyukyfairy: Well, you don't have to do it. I expanded it because doing so may make it easier for you to understand what happens.

Comment: Yeah, I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: @Oyukyfairy: You are welcome!